# Pulling data from Graph at mouse hover points using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

#### I do not have API access

I’m using Selenium (Python) for this Task. 
The graph is present here, https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/flags-general/dark-unica

More specifically I need the data that gets displayed when the mouse hovers to a specific point.

#### These are the approaches I’ve tried:

1. Extracting the **"d"** part of the “path” tag, when I do so I get different values from the one shown on the site so I can’t search for specific points.
2. Trying to get the page source, after doing this I get all NULL values.
3. The “scrollintoview” option to detect points, which returns an empty list.

Comment: Can you give an example of a data you are looking for? How should it look like?

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure which actions you are trying to do, but assuming you already hover a mouse at a point, to get the text use the following:

To get  `USD to EUR:`  text only use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".highcharts-label.highcharts-tooltip-box.highcharts-color-0>text[data-z-index]>tspan:nth-of-type(1)")
```

To get currency value use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".highcharts-tooltip-box.highcharts-color-0>text[data-z-index]>tspan:nth-of-type(2)")
```

Note, that in the second locator I have remove one class and locator is still unique.

So the approach is to use hover actions. For this you will need to use `ActionChains`:
Small example how to use:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

locator = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath where you need to move a mouse")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(locator)
actions.click().perform()
```

After you click the point you need, extract text like:

```
currency_value = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".highcharts-tooltip-box.highcharts-color-0>text[data-z-index]>tspan:nth-of-type(2)").text
```

Comment: Hey, the XPath for the locator always gives me an error, "unable to locate element".

Comment: Which xpath are you using?

Comment: What actions do you do to get to it?

Answer (score 0):

This Xpath works to find the values at points A, B, and C.

`//div//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='g' and @class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-flags-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-tracker"]//*[@data-z-index='1']`